# why my Button hover function isn't working?

Tags: css, reactjs, react-bootstrap

Hi guys so I'm trying to use react-bootstrap to create my app and I want my button to change style when hovered on. I already make the css but it won't work, it didn't change when I hover the button. I tried to inspect the element but there's nothing wrong with it. anyone know why it happens ?

Here's my code:

```css
.facsButton:hover{
    font-size: 40px;
    font-weight: 600;
    color: #10255A;
}
```

```html
<Container fluid>
    <Row className="facsbuttwrapper text-center">
        <Col sm={4} lg={4}>
            <Button
            value="1"
            variant="custom"
            className="facsButton"
            style={{
                fontSize: "32px",
                fontWeight: "500",
                color: "#10255A",
            }}
            onClick={(e) => setCurrentId(e.target.value)}
            >
            De'Spa
            </Button>
        </Col>

        <Col sm={4} lg={4} className="RestoButton">
            <Button
            value="2"
            variant="custom"
            className="facsButton"
            style={{
                fontSize: "32px",
                fontWeight: "500",
                color: "#10255A",
            }}
            onClick={(e) => setCurrentId(e.target.value)}
            >
            De'Resto
            </Button>
        </Col>

        <Col sm={4} lg={4}>
            <Button
            value="3"
            variant="custom"
            className="facsButton"
            style={{
                fontSize: "32px",
                fontWeight: "500",
                color: "#10255A",
            }}
            onClick={(e) => setCurrentId(e.target.value)}
            >
            Meeting Room
            </Button>
        </Col>
    </Row>
</Container>
```

Answer (score 4):

[Rules from stylesheets have a lower priority than rules in an inline style declaration from a style attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity):

> Inline styles added to an element (e.g., `style="font-weight: bold;"`) always overwrite any styles in external stylesheets, and thus can be thought of as having the highest specificity.

You should use a stylesheet for both (and **remove the inline style declaration**):

```css
.facsButton{
    font-size: 32px;
    font-weight: 500;
    color: #10255A;
}

.facsButton:hover{
    font-size: 40px;
    font-weight: 600;
    color: #10255A;
}
```

Alternatively you can use `!important` but that's an anti-pattern:

> When an `important` rule is used on a style declaration, this declaration overrides any other declarations. Although technically `!important` has nothing to do with specificity, it interacts directly with it. Using `!important`, however, is **bad practice** and should be avoided because it makes debugging more difficult by breaking the natural [cascading](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Cascade) in your stylesheets.
>
> [...]
>
> How !important can be used:
> A) Overriding inline styles
> Your global CSS file that sets visual aspects of your site globally may be overwritten by inline styles defined directly on individual elements. Both inline styles and `!important` are considered very bad practice, but sometimes you need the latter to override the former.
>
> In this case, you could set certain styles in your global CSS file as `!important`, thus overriding inline styles set directly on elements.

```css
.facsButton:hover{
    font-size: 40px !important;
    font-weight: 600 !important;
    color: #10255A !important;
}
```

(Side note: `color: #10255A;` seems to be the same for both states, so it wouldn't have to be specified in the hover state at all.)